# CS0176 Member 'Configuration.BankBalances' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead Any help im lost on this

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
  public class Configuration : IRocketPluginConfiguration
    {
    public static Dictionary<string, decimal> BankBalances = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
    public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> GroupMembers = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        public void LoadDefaults()
        {
            // Initialize the static dictionaries
            BankBalances.Clear();
            GroupMembers.Clear();
        }

        public void Load()
        {
            try
            {
                string pluginDirectory = BankingPlugin.Instance.Directory;
                string configFile = Path.Combine(pluginDirectory, "BankingPluginConfig.xml");

                if (File.Exists(configFile))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(configFile))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));
                        Configuration loadedConfig = (Configuration)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

                        // Update static fields directly from loadedConfig
                        BankBalances = loadedConfig.BankBalances; //Error 'Configuration.BankBalances' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead
                        GroupMembers = loadedConfig.GroupMembers; //Error 'Configuration.GroupMembers' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions that occur during loading
                Rocket.Core.Logging.Logger.LogError($"Error while loading configuration: {ex}");
            }
        }
```

I assume this has something to do with me using static on the dictionaries however if i dont then it wont work. I've looked up the issue but couldn't find anything that really relates to what im doing. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Why does it not work, if you don't use `static`?

Comment: so, i think youve misunderstood how statics work in a class, sure, all instances of the class have access to the same variable, but it is a class level variable so, Class.Variable, it is not part of the instance. so not myinstance.Variable

Comment: @RetiredNinja: "Since it is static that means every instance contains the same variable" - I tend to find that gives a misleading impression. It's not that every instance contains the same variable, it's that the variable isn't part of *any* instance; it's related to the type, not to any particular instance of the type.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionaries

```
public static Dictionary<string, decimal> BankBalances = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> GroupMembers = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

are [**static**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) and thereby do not belong to any instance of your `Configuration` class. They rather belong to the type itself completely decoupled from instances and you access them via the type itself:

```
Configuration.BankBalances
```

---

So the question you have to solve yourself now is

**Are those even supposed to be and remain `static` at all?**

- If so, then as said they are "shared" between all instances and copying

  ```
  BankBalances = loadedConfig.BankBalances;
  ```

  wouldn't make any sense as both `BankBalances` here *would* refer to the very same dictionaries anyway (theoretically since as said above code isn't even possible).
- From your usage and deserialization attempts though it rather looks like those shouldn't be `static` at all in the first place.

  If those are supposed to be deserialized from the XML they would need to be instance members anyway and can't be static.